# How to get a method to run only after another method runs to completion

Tags: java, if-statement, wait

I'm making a simple game involving lots of GUIs. The first time a user plays, I want the program to first open GameStart();. In there, the user learns the story, picks a class, and sets a name. A boolean variable gameStarted will be marked as true when the user clicks the last button in the GameStart class.

Now, any time the user opens the game again and loads a save file, gameStarted is true so it will skip the intro stuff.

My problem is that as is, the program doesn't execute anything after the first if statement. Below is what I have.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (!gameStarted){
        new GameStart();
        //use setters
    }

    if(gameStarted){
        //do the rest of the game
    }
}
```

If in between the if statements I add:

```
while(!gameStarted){
    sysout("waiting")
}
```

it works, but obviously the console is flooded with waitings and that's bad. A blank while loop doesn't work. moving my setters from the if statement to the while loop doesn't work unless I have the sysout in there as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: How long is your wait? Read about threads.

Comment: `gameStarted` should be `volatile`.

Comment: Also, consider using more standard [signaling methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

Comment: Threads did the trick. I don't know why more of the examples I was looking for didn't include threads.